# Page scrape for a particular div

Tags: java, html

I am wondering if there is a way to read the html output of a given webpage using Java?

I know in php you can do something like:

```
$handle = @fopen("'http://www.google.com", "r");
$source_code = fread($handle,9000);
```

I am looking for the Java equivalent.

Additionally, once I have the rendered html are there any Java utilities that would allow me to strip out a single div by its id?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: [jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

You have the choice between a tree model and a powerful query syntax similar to CSS or jQuery selectors, plus utility methods to quickly get the source of a webpage.

To quote from their website:

> Fetch the Wikipedia homepage, parse it to a DOM, and select the
>   headlines from the In the news section into a list of Elements:
>
> ```
> Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
> Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
> ```

Once you found the `Element` representing the `div` you want to remove, just call [`remove()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#remove%28%29) on it.

Comment: I wasn't clear on what I meant by strip out.  I want to strip out a particular div into a variable and discard the rest of the page. ANy ideas on how I'd do that?

Comment: Oh, that should be as easy as `Element someElement = doc.getElementById("someId")` :)